# How to refresh the states of ParentStatefulWidget from ModalBottomSheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and I don't have proper idea about the states of a widget. I'm creating an application where I'm adding some items to the cart from home screen and by clicking on Cartbutton I'm opening ModalBottomSheet where user can also modify their cart items, and what I want when user close the ModalBottomSheet without proceeding for checkout. it refreshes the selected items at home screen as well. I'm calculating addition and subtraction of each item into a list. Everything is working fine, the only thing which is not working is home screen items did not updates automatically untill I click on to that item and then they works fine.

**Basically I want to ask how to update states of Parent of BottomModalSheet on closing it.**

Here is a part of code of Parent where I'm opening BottomModalSheet:

```
  child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.black12,
                            onTap: () async{

                               await scaffoldKey.currentState
                                  .showBottomSheet((context) =>
                                 StatefulBuilder(
                                   builder: (BuildContext context,StateSetter setState){
                                     return  Container(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

                                       child: Column(
                                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                         children: <Widget>[
                                           Container(
                                             height: 200,
                                             color: Colors.black,
                                           ),
```

And This is the part of BottomModalSheet where I'm Setting the state:

```
                                                        InkWell(
                                                         onTap: (){

                                                                               totalItems.remove(1);
                                                                               totalPrice.remove(int.parse(categoryItemList[index].OurPrice));
                                                                               cart.remove(categoryItemList[index]);
                                                                               setState(() {<----------------------------------------Here I'm calling setState()
                                                                                 if(categoryItemList[index].Counter<2)
                                                                                 {
                                                                                   categoryItemList[index].ShouldVisible = !categoryItemList[index].ShouldVisible;

                                                                                   if(totalItems.length<1)
                                                                                   {
                                                                                     showCart = !showCart;
                                                                                   }
                                                                                 }else{
                                                                                   categoryItemList[index].Counter--;
                                                                                 }

                                                                               });
                                                                               print(categoryItemList[index].Counter);
                                                                               //  print(searchedItemList[index].Counter);
                                                                             }
                                                                             ,child: Container(
                                                                             height: 30,

                                                                             child: Icon(Icons.remove,color: Colors.green,size: 18,))
                                                                         ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Every Navigator push metod is async - you can wait till it poped

showModalBottomSheet under the hood pushes route to navigator, so you can rebuild your parent after bottomSheet closed this way

```
// somewhere in statefull parent
onTap:() async {
  await showModalBottomSheet();
  setState((){});
}
```

Comment: Hello @Sergey Salnikov, I tried adding async but not able to rebuild my parent screen. I've added the code as well so you can review whether I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please review my code snippet - you forgot to call setState of parent widget.
As I see in your snippet

Comment: I've mentioned in my code where I'm calling setState() please correct me If I did it wrong.

Comment: add `setState` below call `await scaffoldKey.currentState
                                  .showBottomSheet((context) => ... ;`

Comment: @Sergey Salnikov Really! This is very helpful solution