# Rebuild Parent Widget after closing BottomModalSheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

Here is my code of BottomModalSheet:

```
 onTap: () async{

                               await scaffoldKey.currentState
                                  .showBottomSheet((context) =>

                                 StatefulBuilder(

                                   builder: (BuildContext context,StateSetter setState){
                                     return
                                       Container(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,

                                       child: Column(
                                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                         children: <Widget>[
                                           Container(
                                             height: 200,
                                             color: Colors.black,
                                           ),
                                           Container(
                                             height: 100,
                                             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                             color: Colors.cyan,
                                             child: Padding(
                                               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                               child: Column(
                                                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                   Text('DELIVERY AT',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                                                   SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                                   Row(
                                                     children: <Widget>[
                                                       Container(
                                                           margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                                           child: Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.black,)),
                                                       SizedBox(width: 5,),
                                                       Text('Area Code ',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                                                       _userPin!=null?Text(_userPin,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),):Container(),
                                                     ],
                                                   ),
                                                   Container(
                                                       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30,top: 5),
                                                       child: Text('We will try to deliver in 60 minutes',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),))
                                                 ],
                                               ),
                                             ),
                                           ),
                                           Container(
                                             child: Expanded(
                                               child: ListView.builder(
                                                   shrinkWrap: true,
                                                   itemCount: cart.toSet().toList().length,
                                                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                                     return Padding(
                                                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                                       child: Container(
                                                           height: 65,
                                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),color: Colors.black),
                                                           child: Row(
                                                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                             children: <Widget>[
                                                               Padding(
                                                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                                 child: Column(
                                                                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                   children: <Widget>[
                                                                     Container(

                                                                         child: Text('${cart[index].Counter}',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                                                                     Container(
                                                                         child: Text(cart[index].OurPrice,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                                                                     Container(
                                                                         child: Text(cart[index].Name,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),))
                                                                   ],
                                                                 ),
                                                               ),
                                                               Row(
                                                                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                 children: <Widget>[
                                                                   InkWell(
                                                                     onTap: (){
                                                                        if(totalItems.length>=1){
                                                                       totalPrice.remove(int.parse(cart[index].OurPrice));
                                                                       cart.remove(categoryItemList[index]);
                                                                       cart[index].Counter--;
                                                                       totalItems.remove(1);

                                                                       print(totalPrice);}
                                                                        else
                                                                          {
                                                                            print('No item left in cart');
                                                                          }
                                                                       setState(() {


                                                                       });
                                                                     },
                                                                     child: Container(
                                                                       height: 60,width: 50,
                                                                       decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.redAccent,borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10)
                                                                       ,bottomRight: Radius.circular(10))),
                                                                       child: Icon(Icons.delete,size: 28,),
                                                                     ),
                                                                   )


                                                                 ],
                                                               ),
                                                             ],
                                                           )
                                                       ),
                                                     );

                                                   }),
                                             ),
                                           ),
                                           Padding(
                                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                             child: Container(
                                               margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                               height: 50,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                               decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                               child:Center(child: Text('Proceed to Checkout',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)) ,
                                             ),
                                           )
                                         ],
                                       ),
                                     );

                                   }
                                 ),



                              );


                            },
```

Here I'm attaching my screenshots :

ScreenShot 1:ss1

[image]

ScreenShot 2:ss2

[image]

On Clicking cart in screenshot 1, I'm opening BottomModalSheet as shown in image 2 and when I press on delete button shown in ss2, one of the item get's deleted and I want the same to be updated on the parent screen i.e. ss1. I tried doing it by making this method async but I failed. Even I want my list Item to be disappear from screen(ss2), when item count of specific item gets 0. I'm able to change the Item count on Ss2 screen, but I want if item count is 1 and when i press delete again it will remove that item from the screen I ss2.

Comment: Use provider or bloc for simple state management.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh the states of ParentStatefulWidget from ModalBottomSheet in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601923/how-to-refresh-the-states-of-parentstatefulwidget-from-modalbottomsheet-in-flutt)

Comment: No this didn't work.